# Does lambda calculus become covariant if you fix the base type instead of the lambda calculus term?

Tags: reference-request, lambda-calculus, semantics, category-theory

In category theory, we are taught that polymorphic functions correspond to dinatural transformations, a k a multivariant natural transformations between functors of mixed variance
$\operatorname{G} \in \mathbf{Set^{op}} \times \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$, if there is one type variable.

I have been investigating another view and wonder if anyone has seen any texts about this alternative view. Instead of looking at particular lambda functions interpreted at different base types and investigating the relationship of the interpretations as dinatural transformations, I propose that you look at all lambda calculus types and functions, when interpreted at a specific, fixed base type $\operatorname{t}$, so that the act of choosing a base type $\operatorname{t}$ indicates a functor $\operatorname{F_t}$. Say that we fix the base type $\operatorname{string}$. Then, any polymorphic function $f$ between the polymorphic types $t_1$ and $t_2$ is mapped to a function $\operatorname{F_{string}}\ f$ between the types $\operatorname{F_{string}}\ t_1$ and $\operatorname{F_{string}}\ t_2$ formed from the appropriate exponentials and products (and coproducts) of the type $\operatorname{string}$ (and possibly other non-varying types, like the terminal object $\operatorname{1}$).

To me, it seems obvious that $\operatorname{F_t}$ preserves polymorphic (associativity of) composition, but I can't prove it. This seems to me like such a fruitful and basic perspective, it seems highly unlikely I am the first one to stumble upon it, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere. Is it a topos thing? I asked the guys over at Math Overflow$^1$, but they didn't recognize it.

So, three options:

1. explain to me why I am mistaken,
2. give me references to read or terms to Google, or
3. help me explore this, apparently new, concept.

I believe it is related to untyped, or "pure", lambda calculus, if you pick lambda calculus types as base objects, so that it becomes an endofunctor for example $\operatorname{F_{a \to a}}$. If we allow coproducts, we get a category much similar to $\mathbf{Set}$, but extended with variables. Please tell me if any part of my question is hard to read.

$^1$ https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453719/where-can-i-learn-about-cartesian-closed-functors-between-categories-of-simply-t

Comment: 1. Your ideas are too vague, we cannot explain where you are mistaken. 2. System F, parametric polymorphism, relational parametricity. 3. How?

Comment: P.S. The guys at MathOverflow gave you a very useful answer which explained quite carefully what your idea amounted to. (Also, it was not the same idea as what you're describing here.)